# SQLite foreign key is not created, OneToMany column is not created either

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, foreign-keys, sqlite-net

I am trying to create SQLite DB, with two tables, where second table has foreign key. Despite using sample code from SQLite-Net Extensions I am still not able to achieve that. Every time I run the code, column is not created.

I am using sqlite-net-pcl (1.3.1) and SQLite-Net Extensions.

```
public class Bus
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string PlateNumber { get; set; }

    [OneToMany]
    public List<Person> Passengers { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Bus))]
    public int BusId { get; set; }
}


        var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var library = Path.Combine(documents, "..", "Library");
        var filename = Path.Combine(library, "database.db3");
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(filename);

        db.CreateTable<User>();
        db.CreateTable<Purchase>();

        db.CreateTable<Bus>();
        db.CreateTable<Person>();
```

I should have two tables - Bus and Person. Bus should have 3 columns, but only 2 columns are created.

[image]

Why Passengers column is missing? I guess that is the root cause of the problem (maybe not). Not sure, whether it's somehow related, but for example `[NotNull]` attribute does not work either.
Thanks

EDIT1:

I tried following code, but `Passengers` are null.
SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(filePath);

SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(filePath);

```
        db.DeleteAll<Bus>();
        db.DeleteAll<Person>();

        db.CreateTable<Bus>();
        db.CreateTable<Person>();

        db.Insert(new Bus { PlateNumber = "446s-sef5", Id = 1 });
        db.Insert(new Person { Name = "Petr" , BusId = 1});
        db.Insert(new Person { Name = "George" , BusId = 1});

        var busses = db.Table<Bus>();
        foreach (var bus in busses)
        {

        }
```

[image]

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the functionality of sqlite-extensions. It's not going to create a column for Passengers in the Bus table. ( what would the column type be for List<Person>...? ) 

It is going to allow you to retrieve a bus from the database and have the extension automatically populate the Passengers property with the appropriately linked People objects, but only if you relate the Passengers to the Bus using the BusId property.

Comment: I see, now it makes more sense. With this approach I tried to test it, but it does not work as you described. I used classes above and code which I updated. When I look into `Passengers`, it's always null.